# Issue in registering user using MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am registering user using MVC 5 but on the line `db.SaveChanges()`,  I am getting below error :

> The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error
>   occurred while updating the object context. The `ObjectContext` might
>   be in an inconsistent state.

Inner exception message:

> AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's `key` values
>   conflict with another object in the `ObjectStateManager`. Make sure
>   that the key values are unique before calling `AcceptChanges`.

Comment: Update the model from DB and try again

Comment: @Chamika Sandamal I have updated it many times but its not working.

Comment: Do you have any model changes after db created? if so you have to migrate the db

Answer (score 0):

The error say that you have a duplicate key in you context so it can't be saved. Check your key generation and ensure your keys are unique.

**Update**

If you add a composite key you need to modify the entity validators. Create a class that inherits from `IIdentityValidator` and check your key in the `ValidateAsync` method. Then plug this class in your `ApplicationUserManager` (in the `Create` method). Also make sure to modify the index that entity framework creates for you. You need to add your second key member to the index using this annotation:

```
[Index("UserNameIndex", Order = 2, IsUnique = true)]
public string SecondKeyMember { get; set; }
```

in the `ApplicationUser` class.

I think that this is all it was needed to add a second key member to the ApplicationUser.

Comment: I have created composite key in my db. Is this creating any problem

Comment: then how I will overcome from this